# PyQt4 How to get text from QTextEdit and Cant Create Message Box

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make email client in Python. Im getting following error:

```
def egonder(self):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    usrnam=self.ad.text()
    passwds=self.sifre.text()
    if usrnam=="" or passwds=="":
         QtGui.QMessageBox.warning("Fill every blank.")
    else:
        server.login(usrnam,passwds)
        self.durum.setText("Logging in...")
        mytext=""
        self.mesaj.setPlainText(mytext)
        msg = self.konu.text(),"\n",mytext
        server.sendmail(self.kimden.text(), self.kime.text(), msg)
        self.durum.setText("Email sent.")
```

It gives me following error:

```
  File "eposta.py", line 105, in egonder
    server.sendmail(self.kimden.text(), self.kime.text(), msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 793, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 532, in data
    q = _quote_periods(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 168, in _quote_periods
    return re.sub(br'(?m)^\.', b'..', bindata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 175, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

And when i try to make message box show it gives me error:

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.warning("Fill every blank.")
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QMessageBox.warning(QWidget, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons     buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton):  argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
QMessageBox.warning(QWidget, str, str, int, int, int button2=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
QMessageBox.warning(QWidget, str, str, str, str button1Text='', str button2Text='', int defaultButtonNumber=0, int escapeButtonNumber=-1): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1**

Your line: `msg = self.konu.text(),"\n",mytext`

This is creating a string list. If you `print` it you would see something like:

```
('Something', '\n', 'Something More')
```

SMTP.sendmail requires a string for the message. So try this instead:

```
msg = "{0}\n{1}".format(self.konu.text(), mytext)
```

Please read the docs for [SMTP.sendmail](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) and [string.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string.format#string.Formatter.format)

**Error 2**

You are not passing QMessageBox all the required parameters. At minimum it needs the parent of the messagebox, a title and a message. So if there is no parent:

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(None, "Invalid input", "Fill every blank.")
```

Please read the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#warning)

Comment: @user3755771 Please accept my answer if this has sorted it for you.

Comment: Sorry @Shadow9040 didn't know i should do it. Done

Answer (score -1):

ok with:

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(None, "Invalid input", "Fill every blank.")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: This is not an answer. It is just copies the code given at the end of the accepted answer, and seems to be nothing more than a "works for me" comment.